# Obtener valor de una consulta graphql y mostrar en un input de React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, graphql

Estoy escalando una aplicación que yo no hice y tengo poca experiencia con React y nula con graphql, así que se me dificultan cosas incluso algo obvias, por lo que solicito la ayuda de la comunidad para revisar en dónde me estoy equivocando en mi código.
Traigo un arreglo de información con `graphql` y lo muestro en una tabla. Anteriormente, la query era así:

```
query listarRutas($sort: String, $limit: Int, $start: Int, $where: JSON){
    rutas(sort: $sort, limit: $limit, start: $start, where: $where){
        id
        ubicacion{
            id
            nombre
            
        }
        nombre
        descripcion
        inicio
        fin
        activo
        puntos(sort:"id:asc"){
            id
            lat
            lng
        }
    }
}
```

Pero ahora debo agregar este campo: `preciourbano`

```
query listarRutas($sort: String, $limit: Int, $start: Int, $where: JSON){
        rutas(sort: $sort, limit: $limit, start: $start, where: $where){
            id
            ubicacion{
                ...
                preciourbano
            }
            nombre
            ...
    }
```

Sé que el query está bien hecho porque en la consola me muestra la información:
[image: JSON con respuesta de graphql]

A continuación, muestro la tabla donde se extrae la información del `JSON` y me marca que el campo de `preciourbano` **NO** está definido cuando en el `JSON` aparece como 1.

[image: Input mostrando undefined]

Estoy segura que el error está en las siguientes funciones que pondré, pero le he dado tantas vueltas y no lo encuentro.
Para comenzar, hay una función llamada `RutaSelect` que es donde está almacenada mi query de graphql y envía lo siguiente a la tabla:

```
 const AgregarRutasShoppingCart =(rutasSeleccionadas)=>{
    let arrayObjectRutas =[];

    for (let index = 0; index < rutasSeleccionadas.length; index++) {
        const element = rutasSeleccionadas[index];
       
        let rutaObject={
            id: parseInt(element.value.id),
            nombre: element.value.nombre,
            descripcion: element.value.descripcion,
            fecha_inicio : fecha,
            fecha_fin: fecha,
            inicio: element.value.inicio,
            fin: element.value.fin,
            puntos: element.value.puntos,
            cantidad:1,
            precio:element.value.preciourbano
        };
        arrayObjectRutas.push(rutaObject);
        
    }

    addProductRuta(arrayObjectRutas);
}
```

Esa es la función que envía al contexto donde se "pinta" la tabla mostrada arriba, la cual recibe lo siguiente para poder llenar los campos:

```
 //ciclo para rutas
        for (let index = 0; index < element.rutas.length; index++) {
            const elementR = element.rutas[index];
            sumaToArrays=sumaToArrays+1;
            let rutasObject = {
                id:elementR.id,
                nombre:elementR.nombre,
                descripcion:elementR.descripcion,
                inicio: elementR.inicio,
                fin: elementR.fin,
                cantidad: 1,
                descuento: 0,
                preciourbano: elementR.preciourbano,
                fecha_inicio:fecha,
                fecha_fin:fecha,
                puntos:elementR.puntos
            };
            rutastemp.push(rutasObject);            
        }
        objectProducts.push({
            etiqueta:element.etiqueta,
            sitios:sitiostemp.sort((a,b)=> a.clave.localeCompare(b.clave)),
            rutas:rutastemp.sort((a,b) => a.nombre.localeCompare(b.nombre)),
            lat:element.circulo.center.lat(),
            lng:element.circulo.center.lng(),
            radio:element.circulo.radius
        });
    }
    setProductsArr(objectProducts);
    setCount(sumaToArrays);
}
```

Y para finalizar, éste es el input donde debería verse (agrego el input de `Cantidad` y `Descripción` que sí me funcionan, para que los puedan comparar):

```
 <InputText
                            type="number"
                            value={prod.cantidad}
                            required={true}
                            onChange={e=>{   
                                prod.cantidad=e.target["value"];
                                setCantR(e.target["value"]);
                                UpdateCantidaditemsRutas2(e);
                            }
                            }
                            style={{width: "80%", borderRadius: "25px" }}
                            >
          <InputText
                               style={{border:"0px",color:"black",textAlign:"center",width:"75%"}}
                               value={prod.preciourbano}
                               required={true}
                              >
 <InputTextarea
                                rows={4} 
                                style={{width:"100%",borderRadius: "25px",color:"black", resize: "none"}}
                                value={prod.descripcion}
                            />
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es complicado replicar el problema que se describe, sin embargo parece que la forma de acceder a las propiedades del objeto `ubicacion` es la causa del mismo.

*Consideremos lo siguiente:*

El atributo de la propiedad `ubicacion` es un objeto con 3 propiedades: `id, nombre y preciourbano`:

```
//pseudocodigo en query listarRutas
    ubicación = {
        id,
        nombre,
        preciourbano
    }
```

El query regresa esta información y podemos observar la estructura en la consola:

```
    ubicacion = {
        id: 107
        nombre: "Acapulco"
        preciourbano: 1
    }
```

Ahora, observemos como se esta asignando el atributo `preciourbano` a la propiedad `precio` en la función `AgregarRutasShoppingCart`:

```
 const AgregarRutasShoppingCart =(rutasSeleccionadas)=>{
    let arrayObjectRutas =[];

    for (let index = 0; index < rutasSeleccionadas.length; index++) {
        const element = rutasSeleccionadas[index];
       //asignacion del atributo preciourbano a la propiedad precio
        let rutaObject={
            ...
            precio:element.value.preciourbano
        };
        arrayObjectRutas.push(rutaObject);
    }

    addProductRuta(arrayObjectRutas);
}
```

Parece que la forma de acceder al atributo `preciourbano` puede estar causando el problema de **undefined**, puede que el probelma se corriga asignando la propiedad `preciourbano` del objeto `ubicacion` con la notación punto:

```
 const AgregarRutasShoppingCart =(rutasSeleccionadas)=>{
    let arrayObjectRutas =[];

    for (let index = 0; index < rutasSeleccionadas.length; index++) {
        const element = rutasSeleccionadas[index];
       //asignacion del atributo preciourbano a la propiedad precio
        let rutaObject={
            ...
            precio:element.value.ubicacion.preciourbano
        };
        arrayObjectRutas.push(rutaObject);
    }

    addProductRuta(arrayObjectRutas);
}
```

Se debería verificar también el acceso a las propiedades del objeto `ubicacion`, para la función donde se "pinta" la tabla:

```
//ciclo para rutas
        for (let index = 0; index < element.rutas.length; index++) {
            const elementR = element.rutas[index];
            sumaToArrays=sumaToArrays+1;
            let rutasObject = {
                ...
                preciourbano: elementR.ubicacion.preciourbano,
                fecha_inicio:fecha,
                fecha_fin:fecha,
                puntos:elementR.puntos
            };
            rutastemp.push(rutasObject);            
        }
```

Comment: Ya mismo lo intento, muchísimas gracias. Todavía no sé si sea el problema pero por la genial explicación ya tienes voto positivo.

Comment: Ya me manda el valor de 1 pero sólo dentro esta función:  `const AgregarRutasShoppingCart =(rutasSeleccionadas)=>{
 
    for (let index = 0; index < rutasSeleccionadas.length; index++) {
        const element = rutasSeleccionadas[index];
       
        let rutaObject={
            
           precio:element.value.ubicacion.preciourbano
        };
        arrayObjectRutas.push(rutaObject);
        
    }

    addProductRuta(arrayObjectRutas);
}`

Comment: Lo que haría a continuación es observar `console.log(elementR)` y confirmar si tiene la propiedad `ubicacion`,  en la sección que marcaste como "ciclo para rutas", ponlo dentro del ciclo for. Ahora, no esta muy claro de donde viene `prod` en donde pintas los inputs, haber si puedes agregar más código, saludos

Comment: ¡Ya quedó! :) muchísimas gracias.